# Display ipyvuetify widgets in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use VSCode to do some Jupyter Programming. Specifically I am using the ipyvuetify widget library and none of my displays are showing up. The cell runs and displays in a Jupyter notebook, but I just get an elipsis in VSCode. The elipsis menu has the option to change cell presentation, but the only options available in that dropdown are plain text or ipywidget render. The ipywidget render works for the ipywidgets library but not ipyvuetify.

My guess is that I need to find a way to add ipyvuetify to the dropdown of presentation options, but I have not been able to find a way to do that.

If it helps, here is a sample code that works in the Jupyter notebook but not VSCode

```
import ipyvuetify as ipv

class ipvButton(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.create_widgets()

    # Create the widgets
    def create_widgets(self):
        # Create the start button
        self.start_bt = ipv.Btn(color='primary', children=['Start', ipv.Icon(children=['mdi-play'])])
        # Put the button in a box
        displayBox = ipv.Col(class_="ml-4",children=[
                        ipv.Row(children = [self.start_bt])])
        self.form = displayBox
        #event handler
        def btn_click(widget, event, data):
            print('start')
        self.start_bt.on_event('click', btn_click)

        
dp_app = ipvButton()      
dp_app.form
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a python file directly cannot display components because python terminal itself does not support.

You can use interactive window (**Right click -> Run in Interactive Window -> Run Current File in Interactive Window**):

[image]

[image]

Another way is to install [Jupyter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter) extension which can bring you a jupyter-notebook experience.

Create `.ipynb` file and run the code cell:

[image]